# how to find the sum of the inverse of the roots plus 3.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, polynomials

i was doing a math question on a aops book it was an MAO 1991 question. [image]

I tried to solve it by using synthetic division with 3x^3-14x^2+x+62/x+3 and I continued until I got 4 constants then I fliped all the digits to get the reciprocal since the sum of all the roots is the second coefficient divided by the first.

here are my steps

1. use synthetic division to 'stack' divide $3x^3-14x^2+x+62$ by x+3 constantly until I get 1 variable on the bottom. I got $3x^3+23x^2-26x+148$
2. I take the inverse of the equation I got above $3x^3+23x^2-26x+148$ I get $148x^3-26x^2+23x+3$
3. using vietas the sum of the roots of the equation above($148x^3-26x^2+23x+3$) is -(-26)/148 simplifying I get 13/74. am I right I don't have the answer sheet.

Comment: Ask only one question at a time.

Comment: For the first, Vieta's formulas for the cubic.

Comment: My first try, **which might easily fail** would be to compute $g(x) = f(x -3)$.  The idea is that if $r$ is a root of $f(x) = 0$, then $(r+3)$ is a root of $g(x) = 0.$  This transforms the problem to : compute $\frac{1}{r_1} + \frac{1}{r_2} + \frac{1}{r_3} ~: ~r_1, r_2, r_3~$ are the $3$ roots of $g(x)$.  As the comment of @Deepak indicated, I would then consult [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).

Comment: Please write the actual question. [Using pictures-of-words instead of the words themselves is unhelpful](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/why-image-cannot-be-used-for-explaining-my-maths-problem).

Comment: @user2661923 thx for your comment I tried that but I still don't know if I got the right answer so can you match your answer with mine i got 13/74

Comment: First, please edit your question, to show all of your work, using [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: @user2661923 sorry I couldn't show the synthetic division I don't know how to add that. but is my answer correct.

Comment: My denominator agrees with yours, and my numerator disagrees with yours.  Plausible that I made a mistake. 
 Re the responses that have been left, I suggest that you abandon the synthetic division approach and explicitly compute $f(x-3)$.  Then apply Vieta's rules, noting that $$\frac{1}{r_1} + \frac{1}{r_2} + \frac{1}{r_3} = \frac{r_1r_2 + r_1r_3 + r_2r_3}{r_1r_2r_3}.$$

Comment: As an example, if $g(x) = 2x^2 + x + 1$, then $g(x-3) = 2(x - 3)^2 + (x - 3) + 1 = (2)x^2 + (-5)x + (16).$

Comment: Thank you for updating your question.  Please see my just posted answer.  It is possible that I have made an arithmetic mistake.  However, I did double check my arithmetic.  Please leave me a comment, if you see a mistake in my work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x-3) = (3)(x-3)^3 + (-14)(x-3)^2 + (1)(x-3) + (62)$.

Term by term you have that $f(x-3)$

$= ~~(3)[x^3 + 3(x^2)(-3) + 3(x)(-3)^2 + (-3)^3]$

$+ ~~(-14)[x^2 + 2(x)(-3) + (-3)^2]$

$+ ~~(1)[x + (-3)]$

$+ ~~(62).$

This equals

$(3)x^3 + (-27 - 14)x^2 + (81 + 84 + 1)x + (-81 -126 - 3 + 62).$

This simplifies to

$(3)x^3 + (-41)x^2 + (166)x + (-148).$

Simplifying, by clearing the leading coefficient, you have that

$\displaystyle x^3 + \left(\frac{-41}{3}\right)x^2 + \left(\frac{166}{3}\right)x + \left(\frac{-148}{3}\right) = 0.$

Construing the above equation as $x^3 + Bx^2 + Cx + D = 0$, note that you are (in effect) being asked to compute

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{r_1} + \frac{1}{r_2} + \frac{1}{r_3} ~: ~r_1,r_2,r_3$ are the roots of the equation.

This is equivalent to computing $\displaystyle \frac{r_1r_2 + r_1r_3 + r_2r_3}{r_1r_2r_3}.$

Per Vieta's rules, this is equivalent to computing
$\displaystyle \frac{C}{-D}$, 
where $\displaystyle C = \frac{166}{3}, D = \frac{-148}{3}.$

This computes to $\displaystyle \frac{166}{148} = \frac{83}{74}.$

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)$ has roots $x_1,...x_k$ then $g(x)=f(x-3)$ has roots $x_1+3,...x_k+3$. If $h(x)=g(1/x)$ has roots $\frac{1}{x_1+3},...\frac{1}{x_k+3}$. Now using the formula for sum (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) of roots you can find the sum  without actually solving the roots.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$k={1\over a+3}+{1\over b+3}+{1\over c+3}$$
Since $k$ is symmetric in $a, b \text{ and }c,$ it can be expressed
in terms of the elementary symmetric functions for $a, b \text{ and }c.$
If $A=a+3,$ etc., then $$k={BC+AC+AB\over ABC}$$
To get the final answer, you'll only need to use that
$a+b+c={14\over3},$ $ab+ac+bc={1\over3}$ and $abc=-{62\over3}.$
(You can use Wiki to see how the coefficients of the given $f(x)$ are
related to the the elementary symmetric functions.)
P.S. Please learn enough of the TeX code used here to re-type your
question. If you select (in the correct way) any formula on this site,
you can see, copy, paste and then modify the formula's code.

Comment: Please see my posted answer, which seems to disagree with yours.  It is plausible that I have made an analytical or arithmetic mistake.  If so, please advise.